# Чтение всех WAV файлов, находящихся в папке

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловая-система

Как реализовать последовательное чтение всех WAV файлов, находящихся в одной папке?

Необходимо провести спектральный анализ каждого WAV файла, находящегося в папке. Для чтения файла используется функция `wav.read`. Далее данные сохраняются в виде массива `numpy` и проходят дальнейшую обработку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу:

```
import os
import glob
from scipy.io import wavfile as wav

my_dir = r'C:\Windows\Media'

def process_wavs(files):
    for f in files:
        rate, data = wav.read(f)
        # process data here
        print('Rate:\t{}\tShape:\t{}\t["{}"]'.format(rate, data.shape, f))

files = glob.glob(os.path.join(my_dir, '*.wav'))
process_wavs(files)
```

Вывод:

```
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (54080, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (28480, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\chord.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (17504, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\ding.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (29504, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\ir_begin.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (31552, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\ir_end.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (44672, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\ir_inter.wav"]
Rate:   22050   Shape:  (13591, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\kaka.Wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (57088, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\notify.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (27936, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\recycle.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (22048, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\ringout.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (38400, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Speech Disambiguation.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (17792, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Speech Misrecognition.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (47104, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Speech Off.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (36864, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Speech On.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (32192, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Speech Sleep.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (71296, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (44544, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Balloon.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (53696, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Battery Critical.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (44864, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Battery Low.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (39808, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Critical Stop.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (18144, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Default.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (47936, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Ding.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (42880, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Error.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (60060, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (4960, 2)       ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Feed Discovered.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (22144, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Hardware Fail.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (25184, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Hardware Insert.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (23552, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Hardware Remove.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (5816, 2)       ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Information Bar.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (47586, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Logoff Sound.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (39342, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Logon Sound.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (6520, 2)       ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Menu Command.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (32384, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Minimize.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (2824, 2)       ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Navigation Start.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (56832, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (21376, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Pop-up Blocked.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (88448, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Print complete.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (23840, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Recycle.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (38720, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Restore.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (49728, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Ringin.wav"]
Rate:   22050   Shape:  (11013,)        ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Ringout.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (42350, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Shutdown.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (9584, 2)       ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows Startup.wav"]
Rate:   44100   Shape:  (20352, 2)      ["C:\Windows\Media\Windows User Account Control.wav"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Получение списка `wav` файлов, лежащих в директории `yourDIR` и вывод на печать поэлементно:

```
import os

yourDIR = 'C:/WAVdir/'
files = os.listdir(yourDIR)
filelist = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.wav'),files)

for i in filelist:
    print i
```

При необходимости, код можно использовать с любым иным фильтром, вместо приведенного `.wav`.